Traceroute not working in VirtualBox, Ubuntu
I ran traceroute google.in from. an Ubuntu machine running in VirtualBox, but only the first hosts were shown, therest all came as * * *. However, it works as expected
when I do sudo traceroute -I google.in.
Is there a way to I get the full list of hosts using only traceroute with the default UDP packets, without using the -I flag?
Thanks.

If -I does what you want, why not just use it? Is it causing other issues?

@terdon actually its using the ncmp packets not using the U dp packets.

I would first look at connectivity with ip link and ip route. Is the right interface "UP"? What is it connected to? Does the default route point to your router/gateway? Can you ping it? Does host google.com give useful information? @green_32 is sloppily incorrect. traceroute uses ICMP (Internet Control Message Protocol), not UDP. tracepath uses TCP packets.

@waltinator,please don't call people who come here with a question "sloppily incorrect". If they had all the answers they would be asking!

@terdon What would you call "using the ncmp packets not using the U dp packets", where ICMP and UDP were correct? Should I let this wrongness stand?

@waltinator why do you need to "call it" anything? If something is wrong, correct it, don't characterize it.

@waltinator By default traceroute on linux uses UDP by default, not ICMP. Windows however, will default to ICMP, not UDP.  Your accusation of sloppiness is unfounded. And traceroute can also use TCP.

did you try tcp syn probes? some firewalls might block udp and icmp but allow tcp packets sudo traceroute -T google.in

Are the machines that show up even without the -I option all under your control? Is the first machine not showing up also under your control?
